# how do I make Intellisense work for F# in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, f#, intellisense

I am using VS Team System 2008 version 9.0.21022.8 RTM, .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

I get C# and VB.NET Intellisense, but not for F# May 2009 CTP.

**UPDATE July 7th, 2009**

I am installing VS 2008 SP1, maybe it is better than reinstalling VS 2008 from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to reinstall to fix this problem. Installing the VS 2008 Service Pack 1 fixed Intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

Might you have run into [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowssdk/archive/2008/02/22/workaround-installing-win-sdk-after-vs2008-breaks-xaml-intellisense.aspx) problem? (Note, though the title says XAML, the article also indicates that it breaks F# intellisense.)

I have also read that uninstalling and reinstalling F# fixed the problem.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling did not fix the problem. I checked the registry  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{73B7DC00-F498-4ABD-AB79-D07AFD52F395}\InProcServer32 and found there is a problem. Then, I tried registering the DLL as suggested in the link above ( regsvr32 "%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\TextMgrP.dll” ) but I am getting an error and it won't register.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed F# via the MSI Installer file (vs. the .zip install), all that's required is that you have the correct extension on your file: .fs, .fsx, or .fsi.

You can tell if the F# Visual Studio components were installed correctly by going to the Help -> About Microsoft menu option. You should see Microsoft Visual F# in the list of installed products. If you don't see it there, it wasn't installed correctly and that's likely why you're not getting intellisense.